# Assign URLs to multiple buttons without onClick

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, button

I am building a quiz with Webflow handling most of the front end load but want to add in a script so I can easily change all the URLs in one place without opening all the different pages, as there will be a lot of pages and buttons to update in the end.

onClick doesn't work very well in Webflow so I had to come up with a solution without, which I've listed below. Is this the most efficient way of doing this?

I've explored arrays and would love it if I have the const, functions and listeners in their own array formats but I can't figure it out.

```
const openButton = document.getElementById('q1');
const openButtonTwo = document.getElementById('q2');
const openButtonThree = document.getElementById('q3');
const openButtonFour = document.getElementById('q4');
const openButtonFive = document.getElementById('q5');
const openButtonSix = document.getElementById('q6');


//callback for the 'click' event
function openPage(){
    window.location.assign("http://www.google.com/search?q=1");
} 

function openPageTwo(){
    window.location.assign("http://www.google.com/search?q=2");
} 

function openPageThree(){
    window.location.assign("http://www.google.com/search?q=3");
} 

function openPageFour(){
    window.location.assign("http://www.google.com/search?q=4");
} 

function openPageFive(){
    window.location.assign("http://www.google.com/search?q=5");
} 

function openPageSix(){
    window.location.assign("http://www.google.com/search?q=6");
} 



//add the listener
openButton.addEventListener("click", openPage);
openButtonTwo.addEventListener("click", openPageTwo);
openButtonThree.addEventListener("click", openPageThree);
openButtonFour.addEventListener("click", openPageFour);
openButtonFive.addEventListener("click", openPageFive);
openButtonSix.addEventListener("click", openPageSix);
```

I've been exploring arrays but I am not sure that they work how I want them to. I want them to do the below but I can't find any documentation on whether this is even possible (I assume not...)

```
const openButton, openButtonTwo, openButtonThree, openButtonFour, openButtonFive, openButtonSix = document.getElementById('q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6');
```

Same for the functions and listeners

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure where you learned `document.getElementById('q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6');`

Comment: this is why classes exist.

Answer (score 0):

Closures would be the best way to do this, unless you can take the other approach I mention below. You should also make use of classes to get all the buttons.

Closures let you create a function with some data as part of it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures if you're interested in learning how this works.

First, in your HTML, you need to add a class to all of your buttons, maybe called "questionButton". You can also remove the q1-6 ids from them unless you're using them somewhere else. Then you can get a reference to all of them in order (assuming they go from 1-6 in the order of the HTML file) like this:

```js
// This works like a CSS selector if you've used them before \/
const questionButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".questionButton");
/* You might want to replace this line with:
const questionButtons = [...document.querySelectorAll(".questionButton")];

if you plan on using this variable anywhere else,
as it's normally a weird type of array for weird backwards compatibility reasons

The [...<expression>] means make a new array with these items.
It can be quite useful sometimes, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax if you're interested
*/
```

And then you can add the events like this:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < questionButtons.length; i++) {
  // ^ It's important that let is used here instead of the older var, as otherwise it'll be the same variable for every iteration of the loop
  let questionButton = questionButtons[i];
  
  function openQuestion() {
// ^ It's important that the function is defined here, as otherwise the variables i and questionButton wouldn't be accessible as they'd be out of scope
    window.location.assign(`http://www.google.com/search?q=${i + 1}`);
    /* ^ I'm using a string template here, but this line is equivalent to:
    window.location.assign("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + (i + 1));
    */
  }
  questionButton.addEventListener("click", openQuestion);
}
```

And if you did want to write that last line you provided, you'd do it like this: (although you'd still probably want to use a class)

```js
const [openButton, openButtonTwo, openButtonThree, openButtonFour, openButtonFive, openButtonSix] = document.querySelectorAll("#q1, #q2, #q3, #q4, #q5, #q6");
```

The square brackets in the variable name means that those variables should be created using the items in the array. So openButton would be the first item of the array (index 0), openButtonTwo would be the second, etc.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Side point: ideally you should be using anchor elements ("a" tags) with correct hrefs instead of using buttons for this, for SEO and accessibility reasons. If there's a reason for doing it this way that you haven't explained, could still use anchor tags but use event.preventDefault in the click event listener. That way they'll act like buttons but appear to be links. Just make sure the href matches where JavaScript will take you to, otherwise there's not that much point.

Hope this helps.